# getWritableDatabase throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I've trawled through existing NPE/database threads but couldn't find anything directly relevant...

I have an OnClickListener class (separate from the associated Activity class) which calls the createFromPreset method in the code below. The last line in the method code below (this.getWritableDatabase) throws a NPE . When I debug the code and break at that line "this" is showing as "TableControllerMealItem" (not null as I was expecting).

This code was previously working fine. It could be a coincidence, but I just created an Application class (and registed it in the Android Manifest). Could this be messing with anything??

```
public class TableControllerMealItem extends MySQLiteHelper {
    public TableControllerMealItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
public long createFromPreset(meal_item meal_item, long meal_id, long preset_item_id) {
        String presetDesc = "";
        int presetMinutes = 0;

        //Get details from the preset_item (description and minutes)
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM preset_item WHERE _id = " + preset_item_id;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Here's the LogCat:

```
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.ian.mealtimer.TableControllerMealItem.createFromPreset(TableControllerMealItem.java:56)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.ian.mealtimer.OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem.onClick(OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem.java:40)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-27 11:58:39.613: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The MySQLite helper class is here:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "MySQLiteHelper";
    public static final String TABLE_PRESET_ITEM = "preset_item";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRESET_DESC = "preset_desc";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRESET_MINUTES = "preset_minutes";
    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mealtimersqlite.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "mealtimersqlite.db", null, 5);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String SQLCommand;

        SQLCommand = "CREATE TABLE preset_item( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "preset_desc TEXT NULL, preset_minutes INTEGER NULL );";
        db.execSQL(SQLCommand);

        SQLCommand = "CREATE TABLE meal(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "meal_desc TEXT NULL, meal_ready_time INTEGER NULL, meal_reminders_flag INTEGER NULL);";
        db.execSQL(SQLCommand);

        SQLCommand = "CREATE TABLE meal_item(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "meal_item_desc TEXT NULL, meal_item_minutes INTEGER NULL, meal_item_start_time INTEGER NULL, "
                + "meal_item_ready_time INTEGER NULL, fk_meal_id INTEGER NOT NULL, fk_preset_item_id INTEGER NULL );";
        db.execSQL(SQLCommand);
        Log.d(TAG, "Mealtimer Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS preset_item;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meal;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meal_item;");
        Log.d(TAG, "Mealtimer Database Tables Dropped;");
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Here's the class that calls the createFromPreset method:

```
public class OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem implements OnClickListener {
    public final static String EXTRA_MEAL_ID = "com.ian.mealtimer.MEAL_ID";
    private long glbMealId = 1;
    Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    public OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.glbMealId = ((MealTimerApplication) activity.getApplication()).getMealId();
        }
    public void onCreate(long meal_id) {
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        //INSERT a meal_item using then preset_item_id of clicked item
        //then return to the MealItemDetail Activity

        //First get the id of the selected item
        Long selectedPresetItem = Long.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());

        //Now insert the meal_item record

        // Save new meal_item record
        meal_item meal_item = new meal_item();
        long newRecord = new TableControllerMealItem(
                context).createFromPreset(meal_item, glbMealId, selectedPresetItem);
```

Comment: `this` can never be `null` since it refers to the current instance.  The problem must be somewhere in `getWritableDatabase()`.  Possibly a configuration issue?

Comment: Other methods in the TableControllerMealItem work fine, using exactly the same code (SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();) ???

Comment: How do you create `MySQLiteHelper`? Do you pass the context?

Comment: i am sure the context you are passing is null.thats why you get java.lang.NullPointerException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

Comment: I've appended the code of the class that calls this to my original question (can't work out how to format code in comments!) - the call is the last line

Comment: Having just debugged this again, the context in the method call is indeed null (long newRecord = new TableControllerMealItem(             context).createFromPreset(meal_item, glbMealId, selectedPresetItem);)..............but I don't understand why, and how to fix it. ????

Answer (score 2):

The `Context` that you are passing to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor is `null`.

Comment: Presumably I need to set the context in the OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem class, but can't work out how/where to do it. I've tried "this.context = context" in the onCLick method, but that had no effect. ???

Comment: try to get the context of app by making a class and extend it with application class. make this  class as singleton and it will return context of app.and dont forget to add that in manifest file in application tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `context` member variable in your `OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem` is never initialized and it has the default value `null`.

Passing a `null` for a `Context` to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor leads to the NPE in `getDatabaseLocked()` once e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` is called on the helper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the local member `Context` from the `Activity` argument passed in to `OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem()`:

```
public OnClickListenerSelectPresetItem(Activity activity) {
  this.activity = activity;
  this.context = activity;  // Activity is derived from Context
  this.glbMealId = ((MealTimerApplication) activity.getApplication()).getMealId();
}
```

This works because [`Activity` is dervied from (a subclass of) `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Aaah...thank you! I'm still getting my head around the context thing. Your last statement almost makes sense to me!